# pip failed to install cffi w/o gcc

Tags: python, pip, python-cffi

`pip install cffi` fails with error `gcc: command not found` in docker container on image `python:3.7.4-slim`
This is pretty unusual and works till yesterday

Of course, i can run `apt install libcairo2-dev gcc`, but is there any way to avoid compiling from sources?

Answer (score -2):

Issue is resolved by itself somehow